# How to create a script to merge several sheets in another one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sory for my English, this is not my strength!

I am working for a NGO that charges training sessions.

We have a google sheet that compiles datas about participants at each training days one by one in different spreadsheets.

So my yearly document is composed of something like 30 spreadsheets.
I would like to create one more spreadsheet that would merge all the data from other tabs in order to :
- be able to see quickly who has not payed yet his bill
- calculate the total amount made

I know I can do it by using the Filter function but it is really time-consuming for so many spreadsheets and if I add a training session I would have to change the formula. Moreover, I will be forced to do it each year.

So I would like to create a button to import all the data in a new spreadsheet.

You will find an example of the sheet with only 2 spreadsheets here :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RxzUGJFXnU3_mJ3Qj0MCTpwPTlnmgIT439AchyrRrE/edit?usp=sharing

I hope you would be able to help me!!

Thanks and happy new year :D

Answer (score 0):

## Merging Sheets in another sheet in same spreadsheet.

You will need the id for spreadsheet named 'CopiDdeFCCE' the other parameter will default to 'CopieDdeFCCE'.

```
function mergeSpreadsheet(ssid,shname){
  var shname=shname || 'CopieDdeFCCE';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);//id of spreadsheet named 'CopieDdeFCCE' in your case
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shname);//sheetname of sheet where other sheets are merged into again in your case its named 'CopieDdeFCCE'
  if(!sht){ss.insertSheet(shname);}
  var allshts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<allshts.length;i++){
    if(allshts[i].getName()!=shname){//do this for all sheets except shname
      var shi=allshts[i];
      var rg=shi.getDataRange();
      var vA=rg.getValues();
      shi.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,shi.getLastRow(),shi.getLastColumn()).setValues(vA);
    }
  }
}
```

Just to be clear.

- What Google calls the spreadsheet is the file that contains all of the tabs (i.e. sheets).
- In your first comment you said the following: *I would like to merge all the 28 sheets of a file called "CopieDdeFCCE" to a new sheet of the **same file**.*
- But now in your question you say: I would like to create a button to import all the data in a new spreadsheet.
- You stated in your last comment that your command looks like this: mergeSpreadsheet("1KC6kHcgtLZ93S4-r4wOwHFOG6Rq3mesGRKv26Ttnm9E","CopieDdeFFCE")
- But clearly that's not the id of the example and the example does not have a sheet with that name.

> > So my question is: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Sorry @Cooper I think I made a mistake in English, because all my sheets are in the same file (I may have get sheets and spreadsheet mixed up... very sorry!!!).

So, I would like to merge all the 28 sheets of a file called "CopieDdeFCCE" to a new sheet of the same file. Would the same script work?

Thanks a lot and sory for the English terms confusing....

Comment: That's a simple script.  Here it is.

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks again for your quick reply and sory for my delay but with Christmas time I was not working!!!
I have just tried to use this script and I receive this error message :
"You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions". 
Do you have an idea how I can get the permission?

Thanks again, your help is very precious!!!

Comment: Sorry again for bothering you... but when I put the Id of spreadsheet. I am sure it is the good one and here is an other error message :
Missing ) after argument list. (ligne 3, fichier "CopieDdeFCCE")
Where as here is my line :
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(1KC6kHcgtLZ93S4-r4wOwHFOG6Rq3mesGRKv26Ttnm9E);

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You need to add quotes around the id.  It's a string.

Comment: I have just tried but here is the error message :
Missing formal parameter. (ligne 1, fichier "CopieDdeFCCE")

function mergeSpreadsheet("1KC6kHcgtLZ93S4-r4wOwHFOG6Rq3mesGRKv26Ttnm9E","CopieDdeFFCE"){


And for the other problem about the permission, do you have any aidea?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi Cooper, Did you see my last question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very sory I did not receive any notification of your reply because it was an edit and when I came to see if you wrote something I looked at the bottom of the site. :/

First of all, happy new year and thank you again for your help!!

Here are the precisions you asked :

1° Indeed, I would like to merge all the 28 sheets of a file called "CopieDdeFCCE" to a new sheet of the same file. To be more accurate, I give you the link of the exact location of the document with some examples of sheets: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KC6kHcgtLZ93S4-r4wOwHFOG6Rq3mesGRKv26Ttnm9E/edit?usp=sharing).

2° Secondly, I will create a button to update all the data easily. But I think I know how to do that, so forget that question for now ;)

3° In the document I put enclosed, do we agree that the "id" is : 1KC6kHcgtLZ93S4-r4wOwHFOG6Rq3mesGRKv26Ttnm9E ??

Thanks again for all your time!